# Assigning an existing process to an object variable?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I need to assign another application as an object and control it.

Typically, I would open a new instance of the application using CreateObject(), but in this instance I need an existing instance of the object that was already opened in Windows Explorer. The object is an Internet Explorer session that, for various reasons, I can't simply navigate to using web browser controls in Office.

Is there a way to grab this application session by its window handle or something so that I can control it using the APIs that VBA offer? It's also essential that the application stays on the page that it was on and that its entire DOM structure remains intact.

Comment: GetObject seems to have issues with IE. See [Here](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2010/07/getobject-error-with-internet-explorer.html) for a work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in a sub, it works for me

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    If my_title Like "The Title You're Looking For" & "*" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

Now do stuff with this instance of ie
```

Comment: This appears to work, as well, albeit a bit different from the link provided in the comment above. I guess I'll give this best answer since it works. Thanks engineersmnky and ron.